# Regex ignore tags surrounded by anchor

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Is it possible and how, if it is, to select only the tags that are not surrounded by an anchor `<a></a>` tags?
It's not possible for me to change the whole system to use something like `DOMDocument` so I'm stuck with regular expressions.
Have searched for this for a while but can't seem (or don't know how) to find the answer to what I need.

I'm currently using simple regex that will select all of the tags I would like to select, but I have to exclude some of the tags that are surrounded by anchors and am not sure how to fix this. Any help appreciated.

*Sample data*

```
Suspendisse potenti. Nam pellentesque eu lectus eget convallis. 
Curabitur <span>porta metus sem</span>, nec fermentum urna elementum ac. 
Praesent et ultrices urna. <span>Curabitur id nisl</span> in sapien ultrices laoreet vel et quam.
Cras nisi felis, vestibulum id adipiscing venenatis, dignissim vel tortor. 
<a><span>Integer sapien dolor</span></a>, pellentesque sed ultricies in, ornare eu felis. 
Cras volutpat hendrerit odio id aliquet.
```

In this I'd select all the `<span>` tags with something like `'/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/'` but that would select all of the spans, where as I need the span tags that are not encased between `<a></a>`.

A multiple step process is fine as long as it does the work, meaning it is not a requirement to have everything being selected with one expression.

Comment: share some examples of your sample data

Comment: "I'm currently using simple regex" - show it to us and, as Keval mentioned, give us one or two examples on what you want to achieve (input, desired output)

Comment: I've edited my post with sample data and regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
preg_match_all(
  '%\G(?:[^<]+|<a\b[^>]*>.*?</a>|<(?!span\b)[^>]*>)*\K<span[^>]*>.*?</span>%s',
  $subject, $result);
```

Are you *sure* you can't use an HTML parser?  :D

To explain it I'll first put it in a more readable format.

```
\G                        # (1)
(?:
    [^<]+                 # (2)
  |
    <a\b[^>]*>.*?</a>     # (3)
  |
    <(?!span\b)[^>]*>     # (4)
)*
\K                        # (5)
<span[^>]*>.*?</span>
```

Here's how it works:

1. `\G` forces each successive match to start at the position where the previous match ended.
2. anything that's not the start of a tag
3. a complete `<a>` element (assuming they never contain other `<a>` elements)
4. any other tag except `<span>`
5. `\K` resets the match start position, so everything that has been matched so far is not treated as part of the match.  It's effectively a positive lookbehind that doesn't care how many characters it matches.

The usual disclaimers apply.  There are many ways this regex can fail, even in perfectly valid HTML.  For example, it assumes a left angle bracket (`<`) always marks the beginning of a tag, when it can really be found in many other places.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!<a>)<span>(.*?)<\/span>
```

This will exclude `<span>`-tags where an `<a>`-tag is at the beginning.

For the completeness, if you need to match on a full surrounding only, then add a negative lookahead:

```
(?<!<a>)<span>(.*?)<\/span>(?!</a>)
```

See the demo: http://regexr.com?374pp

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!<a.*?>)(<(?!a\b)(.*?\b).*?>.*</\2>|<(?!a\b).*?\b />)(?!</a>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BQD0ZvoXk8tAOk4m)

This should match every HTML tag not surrounded by a-Tags

If you just need a matcher for span-Tags, use this one:

```
(?<!<a.*?>)<span.*?>.*</span>(?!</a>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/L1vny5To0MxKvSFT)

If you need more information about regex lookaround assertions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html